# Firebase Query doesn't work anymore after automatic conversion from Swift 2 to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My query to load `tableViewData` doesn't work anymore. My code below.

```
let imageKeysQuery = ref.child("categories").child("Multimedia").child("Fotos").queryOrdered(byChild: "date")
    imageKeysQuery.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        (snapshot) in

        for (item) in (snapshot.children) {

            if (item as AnyObject).value!["release"] as! Bool != false {

                self.keysForImages.append((item as AnyObject).value!["key"] as! String)
                self.datesForImages.append((item as AnyObject).value!["date"] as! String)

            } else {

                let post = "Freizugeben!"
                let childUpdates = ["/categories/Multimedia/AAAAA-Fotos-Not-Released/\((item as AnyObject).value!["key"] as! String)": post]

                self.ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)

            }

        }

        self.downloadImages()

    })
```

I get an error message in every line where a `(item as AnyObject).value![".."]` is. Below is the error message:

```
Type NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element (aka 'Any') does not conform to protocol AnyObject.
```

UPDATE:

Found a solution:

```
let newsQuery = (ref.child("categories").child("Aktuelles").child("de")).queryOrdered(byChild: "date")
    newsQuery.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        for child in snapshot.children {

            let data = (child as! FIRDataSnapshot).value! as! NSDictionary

            self.titleTableData.append(data["title"]! as! String)
            self.textTableData.append(data["text"]! as! String)
            self.postKeys.append(data["key"]! as! String)
            self.dateTableData.append(data["date"]! as! String)

        }

        self.loadimages()

    })
```

The important thing is to convert child to FIRDataSnapshot as a NSDictionary!

Hope this helps someone.